# vb.net and reflection , need to get a Type from a class name string

Tags: vb.net, reflection

I am building a validation framework that wants to store field names and validations against those field names in a DB table.

What I wanted to do was, given the table name (as string), use reflection to instantiate the get method for specific fields (defined as properties with Get and Set methods.

And example of a get/set pair in one record wrapper.

```
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'---------Get/Set (for field: VC60 
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'

Public Property VC60() As String

    Get
        Return _VC60
    End Get


    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _VC60 = value
    End Set

End Property
```

I can use

```
    Dim t As Type = GetType(DB_TableName)
```

To get the type and use t.GetMembers to get the methods,

but the peice I am missing is how to get the type of the class given the string name of the class.

This is a console application producing a .exe using visual Basic 2008

I have tried accessing a assembly reference with System.Activator.CreateInstance without success.

Answer (score 0):

`GetType` can accept a string as an argument for the type name.  Ensure you're passing a namespace-qualified type name into your `GetType` method and have that assembly available in your project.  Otherwise, you'll just get a null return value.

MSDN: [GetType Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If the type is in mscorlib, you can call `Type.GetType(someString)`.

Otherwise, you'll need to find the `Assembly` instance for the type and call its `GetType(string)` method.